Will the ATGM336H-5N31 GPS module work with Galileo satellites?
I'm using the ATGM336H-5N31 GPS module and wondering if it's compatible with Galileo satellites. The User Manual (LINK) does mention Galileo, but only in regards to the AT6558 - GNSS SOC, which the GPS module internally is built upon.
Looking at the table in 1.2 Product Purchase paragraph, there is no mention of the Galileo system.

Furthermore, table in 2.6 Technical Specifications paragraph mentiones Galileo as Signal receiving indicator, but not in RF channel number which I cannot understand why.

Unfortunately, I've been unable to find the Zhongkewei manufacturer contact for clarification.
Has anyone successfully used this module with Galileo?

It literally says in the 1st paragraph on the 1st page of the datasheet you linked to: "EU Galileo".

@brhans Actually, they are mentioning the GNSS SOC - AT6558 which supports variety of satellite navigation systems, one of which is Galileo. However, looking at the table at 1.2 Product Purchase paragraph, Multi-mode Function for Galileo nav. system is not mentioned as supported one in the whole document, and because of that, I'm searching for a first hand experience with this module to answer my question.
